# Does anyone know of source code to a free bar code reader algorithm?

Tags: barcode

Does anyone know of source code to a free bar code reader algorithm, ideally in a C/C++/C# based language? Something that processes a bitmap picture of a barcode is fine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) yet?